# How invoke private function by name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reflection

How invoke function by name?
Actually I know how invoke function by name, but I can't find needed scope.
So now I have to use **this["*get*" + widgetName]** , it is works for **_get_publishedBuildsWidget1** but I want make function as private.

So I want invoke by name **_get_publishedBuildsWidget2**  function

```
    function widgetGeneratorService(commonDashboardService, $filter, buildService, $state) {

            var widgetGeneratorServiceFactory = {};

            widgetGeneratorServiceFactory._get_publishedBuildsWidget1 = function (widget) {
                widget.name = "Test",
                return widget;
            }
            var _get_publishedBuildsWidget2 = function(widget){
    widget.name = "Test",
                return widget;
    }

            widgetGeneratorServiceFactory.getDefaultWidget = function (widgetName) {
                var defaultWidget = {};
                //TODO rewrite!!!
                var fnGenerateWidget = this["_get_" + widgetName];
                if (typeof fnGenerateWidget === 'function') {
                    return fnGenerateWidget(defaultWidget);
                }


                return defaultWidget;

            }

            return widgetGeneratorServiceFactory;
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't invoke private functions via a string variable except via `eval()`, and that's generally a bad idea.

However you can trivially create a private object that contains *references* to those private methods, and then index into that to get the desired function:

```
function widgetGeneratorService(...) {

    var methods = {
        func1: func1
        ...
    };

    methods['func1']();

}
```